# Delphi XE2 : How can I play video files with firemonkey

Tags: delphi, video-streaming, delphi-xe, vlc, libvlc

I want to make a mediaplayer application using with firemonkey but I can't see any component for videoplayer :( I was trying to integrate VLC (VideoLAN player) to firemonkey but the firemonkey controls don't have window handle.

How can I make or find a videoplayer component ?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

In addition to VideoLab we also offer a much cheaper [BasicVideo](http://www.mitov.com/products/basicvideo). The libraries are also free for non commercial purposes.

MAC and iOS FireMonkey versions are in development at the moment, and will be available in couple of months.

Comment: Did these ever get completed ?

Answer (score 3):

VideoLab from Mitov software (Beta Release for FireMokey) : [VideoLab](http://www.mitov.com/products/videolab)

Download page: [VideoLab 5.0.1 FireMonkey (Windows only) Beta 1 for XE2 Update 2 Only](http://www.mitov.com/installer/53)

Comment: Decidely not cheap (fair enough given that it is somewhat more than just a video *player* product) and no mention of support for anything other than Windows technologies.  Cross platform admittedly may not be important to the OP, but it is worth noting in that FireMonkey creates this dichotomy of two separate platforms for Windows development: VCL and Windows specific FireMonkey.  When someone says "FireMonkey" they really should also say whether they mean cross-platform FireMonkey or some platform specific implementation, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Found at torry:
http://www.flashavconverter.com/

Comment: Rather than just linking, I think it would be worth briefly explaining what it is.  The URL suggest's it may be specific to FLASH video, when in fact it is a FireMonkey implementation of the FFMPEG technology suggested by Marcus.  It is commercial but cheaper than VideoLab and specifically mentions support for both Windows and OSX in the FireMonkey variant (VCL version also available).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a free, popular, powerful, and cross platform method, use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) + [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). This is how VLC does it.