# How to play AVI files with FM?

Tags: delphi, video, firemonkey, avi

Can someone tell me how to play AVI files with FireMonkey? Which component should I use?

I searched in all componenets but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: check this example http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Building_a_Basic_Media_Player

Comment: Depending on your Delphi version, [`XE3 Audio-Video in FireMonkey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Audio-Video_in_FireMonkey) or [`Delphi XE2 : How can I play video files with firemonkey`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8130097/576719).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add TMediaPlayer to your form
2. Add TMediaPlayerControl to your form
3. Add TButton to your form
4. Duoble click on your button
5. Insert this between begin and end tag

`if MediaPlayer1.Media <> nil then
begin
    MediaPlayer1.Play;
end;`

It should look like this:
[image: Screenshot]

6. Change `C:\earth.avi` to the location of your avi file

Result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you play it with the Windows Media Player? Maybe a missing codec or so?

Comment: Yes, Windows Media Player plays it correctly, even I test it with Windows 7 sample video(Wildlife.wmv), but this method cannot play it too!!!

Comment: Maybe contact FireMonkey support? I have no idea what's wrong, sorry.