# How to Play a File Download Animation in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, gif, avi

I want to play a file download animation until a file is downloaded in my form. I want to use the one in Windows, but don't know whether it is an AVI or GIF. I see a place where I can download these files in AVI, but they are very old fashion. Maybe used in Windows XP or earlier version. I want to get a modern one for the Windows 10 or 7.

Also should I convert the AVI to GIF to play it, or whether Delphi can play AVI directly.

Comment: Use the `TAnimate` control, and give it an AVI file to play.

Comment: @KenWhite, Thank you. Where can I find the system default animation files?

Comment: The *system default* animations are in the `CommonAVI` property. They don't include anything for download progress, however.

Comment: @KenWhite, I check the CommonAVI propery. However, there is no animation for downloading file. I find one page at http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/avi/animationzips.htm where there are many old Windows animations, including the one I want, i.e. "Transfer from web". But CommonAVI is much more less than those listed in that page.

Comment: The answer to this question explain how to play an AVI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336394/how-to-play-avi-files-with-fm

Comment: An easier alternative would be using a "in progress" indicator that already comes built into the [VCL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TActivityIndicator) and [FMX](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TAniIndicator)

Comment: @alancc the animations you are looking for are private to the OS’s own dialogs and are not exposed publicly to applications. That vbnet website provides downloads for animations that were extracted manually from the OS.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful, seems that the indicator is not available in XE3?

Comment: @alancc: Yes, I said *They don't include anything for download progress, however.* in my previous comment.