# FMX: Handle of controls

Tags: delphi, controls, handle, firemonkey

I'm working with DirectShow in firemonkey, and i have a problem with outputting Video.

```
iVideoWindow.Put_Owner(Panel1.Handle);
```

I need handle of TPanel, to display video at it. But FMX controls have no handle. I know, that Firemonkey is not based on traditional windows and FMX do not provide this, but how to solve  this problem? I have no idea, please, help me.

Comment: I'd say, you'll be out of luck. Although, you might use a form as the target of the `IVideoWindow.Owner` by converting form's `Handle` with `FmxHandleToHWND` function or take a look at alternative ways of playing video files e.g. at [`How to play video files in Firemonkey`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8130097/960757).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get a window handle as an `HWND` (Win32 API) type, you can now call this function:

```
WindowHandleToPlatform(form1.Handle).wnd
```

Put this in your `uses` clause:

```
uses
  FMX.Platform.Win;
```

Note that just calling `WindowHandleToPlatform(form1.Handle)` will not work, you have to access its `.Wnd` property to obtain the Win32 handle.

Since this makes an application less portable, it is also a good idea to put `{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}` around the code whenever doing this, and if you ever port to MacOS, you'll have to write separate code for that platform. Or, put this code into a separate unit that deals only with MSWindows-related stuff, and `IFDEF` that unit into your `uses`.

Comment: "*you can now call this function*" - or simpler, the [`FormToHWND()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function.

Comment: In addition: That would be the window handle of the form, not the Panel, so you might have issues positioning the video output where you want.

Answer (score 2):

`FmxHandleToHWND` is marked deprecated now.

`WindowHandleToPlatform` will convert given FireMonkey handle to its platform dependent window handle (in your case a Windows handle).

Comment: And even simpler, there is the [`FormToHWND()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function for Win32 `HWND`s specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Use Timage control, then you can assign your output to Image1.Bitmap.Handle. Its the only component that provides window Handle under FMX

Comment: FMX's `TImage` does not provide an `HWND`, only `TForm` does. And the `Bitmap.Handle` is not an `HWND`, nor does it represent anything that can be converted to an `HWND`.

Answer (score -2):

To get handle of a panel, try this :

```
uses 
  FMX.Platform.Win;

var
  Handle : HWND;

begin

  Handle := TWinWindowHandle (Panel1).Wnd;

end;
```

Comment: You can't type-cast a `TPanel` object to a `TWinWindowHandle`.  The only way to get a valid `TWinWindowHandle` is to pass the `TForm.Handle` to [`WindowHandleToPlatform()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform). Or, you can simply use [`FormToHWND()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) instead.